# How to implement quantum gate from matrix in Q#

Tags: programming, q#, matrix-representation

Is it possible to implement a quantum gate from a matrix in Q#, the equivalent of unitary function in Qiskit ? My final goal is to implement cirq CZPowGate in Q#.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumLibraries/issues/291) for a Q# operation to apply an arbitrary unitary operation given its representation as a matrix; if you're interested, please go on and leave a comment on that request!

In the meantime, though, it's actually really straightforward to implement the same unitary operation as `cirq.CZPowGate` in Q#.

```
open Microsoft.Quantum.Math as Math;

operation ApplyCZPow(t : Double, control : Qubit, target : Qubit) : Unit is Adj + Ctl {
    Controlled R1([control], (t * Math.PI(), target));
}
```

This uses the [`R1` operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.r1) provided with the Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic namespace together with the [`Controlled` keyword](https://docs.microsoft.com/quantum/user-guide/using-qsharp/operations-functions#controlled-functor) to apply the same rotation as `cirq.CZPowGate`.

---

To see how this works, note that as per the [Cirq documentation for CZPowGate](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/cirq.CZPowGate.html), that instruction is represented by the unitary matrix
$$
U_{\text{CZPowGate}}(t) = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i \pi t}
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
This is a special case of a controlled operation with a single control qubit, as it has the pattern
$$
\Lambda(U) = \left(\begin{matrix}
 & 0 \\
0 & U
\end{matrix}\right) = |0\rangle\langle0| \otimes  + |1\rangle\langle1| \otimes U
$$
for some unitary matrix $U$. In particular, $U$ in this case represents a rotation that leaves the $|0\rangle$ state alone but that applies a phase to the $|1\rangle$ state; precisely the action of the [`R1` operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.r1).

In Q#, the `Controlled` keyword can be used to get the controlled version of any controllable operation (that is, an operation with `is Ctl` in its signature). Each `Controlled` operation takes as its first input an array of controls, and takes all of the original inputs to the uncontrolled operation as the second input. For example, `CNOT(control, target)` in Q# is shorthand for `Controlled X([control], target)`.
Similarly, a Toffoli in Q# can be written as `Controlled X([control1, control2], target)` and the Fredkin operation can be written as `Controlled SWAP([control], (target1, target2))`.

Using the same pattern here works since `R1` is a controllable operation. We can check  that we get what we expect by using the [`Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics.DumpOperation`  operation](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.diagnostics.dumpoperation) to check the unitary representation of our new `ApplyCZPow` operation ([run online without installing](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/cgranade/b8cefb19b63154f343c790c035a8e161/master)):

```
open Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics as Diag;

operation DumpApplyCZPow(t : Double) : Unit {
    Diag.DumpOperation(2, ApplyToFirstTwoQubitsCA(ApplyCZPow(t, _, _), _));
}
```

[image: Using %simulate to run DumpCZPow]

Comment: Hello Chris, 
Thank you for your answer, I found this way with R1 gate just before seeing you reply, but yours is very clear and complete !

Comment: No worries, @user12910, happy to help!